One-sample multiple importance sampling, with environment and brdf
I am writing a pathtracer, and I want to somehow incorporate importance sampling of the environment map. The obvious way to do this seems to use MIS to either importance sample from my material bsdf or a ray to my environment map. I am having a hard time making it work though, and I am feeling uncertain as to whether I can really say that it is unbiased.
The main problem I have is that if I have a very bright environment light on the opposite side of the material, it will pretty much be sampled at least 50% of time time according to MIS. I should know that sampling that direction won't contribute to reducing variance in any way, as the brdf in that direction is 0. But how can I incorporate this into my MIS "flow" while keeping it completely unbiased???

You could add a third sampling strategy that samples in the general direction of that bright light (e.g., a spherical Gaussian) and compute the MIS weights accordingly. This will remain unbiased.

Not sure I understand your question. You can't know ahead of time what direction to the env map you are sampling, so there's not really any way to know it's BRDF contribution.
